# Array of pointers as function argument

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How do I feed an array of pointers as an argument to a function?

In the code below, if I want my function f to take an array of pointers `int *x[]`, how should I declare x in main() and feed it as argument to f?

```
void f(int *x[]){ 
     int data[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
     int k;
     for(k=0; k<5; k++){ 
        x[k] = &(data[k]);
     }
}

int main(){
    int *(x[]), k, l=5;
    f(x); // this does not work
    for(k=0; k<l; k++){ 
        printf("x[%d] = %d\n", k, *x[k]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Writing `f(x)` does not work, and neither does `f(x[])` or `f(x[5])`.

In fact, the declaration `int *(x[])` is already not recognized by my compiler, while I thought that one could declare an array of pointers without specifying the length of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code has no sense because you are trying to fill an array of pointers that will point to local variables. That is after exiti8ng the function all pointers will be invalid because original objects will be already destroyed.
The code could have a sense if the array in the function would have static storage duration

```
void f(int *x[]){ 
     static int data[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
     int k;
     for(k=0; k<5; k++){ 
        x[k] = &(data[k]);
     }
}
```

In main array x should be defined at least as

```
int * x[5];


int main(){
    int * x[5], k;

    f(x); 

    for ( k=0; k < 5; k++ ){ 
        printf("x[%d] = %d\n", k, *x[k]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `main`, change

```
int *(x[])
```

to

```
int *x[SIZE]; // SIZE is array size
```

Note that, *you can't declare a zero size array in C except when it is a last member of a structure*.

After all, your code will invoke undefined behavior because the variable `data` is an automatic local variable and will not exist after function returns.

You may want this:

```
void f(int *x[]){ 
     int *data = malloc(5*sizeof(int);
     int temp[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
     memcpy(data, temp, 5*sizeof(int));
     int k;
     for(k=0; k<5; k++){ 
         x[k] = &(data[k]);
     }
}
```

Comment: So for this example, I changed it into *x[5]. This still seems to give problems. The output becomes 
x[1] = 1, 
x[2] = 2, 
x[3] = large number,
x[4] = large number,
x[5] = large number.

Comment: Also, is there any way to declare *x[] without specifying the SIZE?

Comment: @Peter; No. You can't.

Comment: @Peter: Depending on what you need, VLA's might help you out. But if nothing else, `int **x = malloc(array_size * sizeof *x);` allocates a block of memory (which you can use as an array) with a size you can determine @ runtime

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to declare an array of pointer as a parameter is to use a pointer of pointer

```
void f(int **x, int size){ 
  //code
}
```

However, you'll have to pass the size as a second argument if you want to avoid an overflow.

To call the code you'll just have to do something like this :

```
int *a[] = { NULL, NULL, NULL};
f(a, 3);
```